# is there a jquery plugin for creating something like organisational hierarchy chart?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, family-tree

I m woring on a genealogy project. I have been trying to find a jquery plugin for creating family tree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a jquery plugin for family trees but you could check out the 
[Google Visualizations Library](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/orgchart.html#Example)

Comment: @Pirus you didn't specify asp.net as a tag, maybe you want to add it to your question